# django howto use select_related not using local id key

Tags: django

i have made two models where i would like to get them joined on the two name keys.

**models.py**

```
class MODELa (models.Model):
    ......
    nameXX = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255, primary_key=True)

class MODELb (models.Model):
    ......
    nameYY = models.CharField(_("nameYY"), max_length=255)
    FKxx = models.ForeignKey(to=MODELa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
rows = MODELb.objects.all().select_related('FKxx')
```

using debug toolbar, i can see the join is using the id field

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "MODELa"
    ON ("MODELb"."FKxx_id" = "MODELa"."nameXX")
```

How do i set it use the local key nameYY?

Comment: Can you share how you want to use the result of this query? You can manipulate the query to join on what you want but the ForeignKey relationship will be the same

Comment: i want to join the two tables on names. it is many to one. there are many at MODELb and they would match one at MODELa